# Duplicating HTML element using Vanilla JavaScript. Not a Single copy, it should be as per requirement

Tags: javascript

How can i duplicate an HTML element as per our custom requirement using Vanilla JS. I usually seen duplicating only a single time, that means duplicating only 1. But i need duplicate the element twice when i click on a button. Also i need to assign custom number of duplicate elements. How can it possible. Following is the code.

This is the Code before implementation:

```
<div class="container">Inner Content</div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Following is i want when i click the button, now it is 2 copy. I need to also assign the numbers of copy . That means if i change it to 3, it should be duplicate 3 element.

```
<div class="container">Inner Content</div>
<div class="container">Inner Content</div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

I was tried the following code:

```
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div class="container">Element Content</div>
<script>
let button=document.querySelector('#button'); 
let container=document.querySelector('.container'); 
function cloneit() {
let cloneip = container.cloneNode(true); 
document.body.appendChild(cloneip); 
}
button.addEventListener('click', cloneit); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see even the javascript code for duplicating once, neither your attempt to modify it to do a double copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
for(i=1;i<3;i++){
    // Clone element
    let clone = document.querySelector('.container').cloneNode( true );
    
    // Change ID of clone with the current i state
    clone.setAttribute( 'id', i );
    
    // Append the newly created element on element p 
    document.body.appendChild( clone );
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayr, i have one more doubt regarding the basic logic of forloop. I though an 'i' is mandatory in the body of forloop to repeate everything. But now i can see that the following forloop also generate 3 hello word. How is it happened without using 'i' in the forloop body. Its just to know the logic: </br>
```for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
document.write('hello world'+'<br>');
}```

Comment: The 'i' is actually the same like a variable, which will be override ( like 1,2,3 ) upon iteration of the current for index. The 'i' does not have to be used within the for loop, but is helpful to make use of in case when you want to iterate over arrays or objects and need values from of the current object index